# Set <span> color during list iteration

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

What I am doing is iterating a list from an array called `items`, and at every iteration it runs a function that gets `item.painted` and if it equals a certain color, it sets `loopColor` to that color and then sets loopColor in the list iteration as the span `color` style.

Everything runs fine, without any errors, but the color doesn't really gets changed.

```js
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="rightTopper">
        <span class="BCN">BCN</span>
        <img :src="bitcoin" />
        <span class="amount">{{ coins }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <ul>
        <li v-for='item in items'>
          {{ getColor(item.painted) }}
          {{ item.name }}
          <span :style="{'color': loopColor}">
            {{ item.painted }}
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import bitcoin from '../assets/bitcoin.svg'

  export default {
    name: 'landing-page',
    data() {
      return {
        coins: 100.0712,
        bitcoin,
        items: [
          {name: 'myst', painted: 'pink'},
          {name: 'dig', painted: 'red'},
          {name: 'zord', painted: 'grey'}
        ],
        loopColor: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getColor: function(color) {
        switch (color) {
          case color === 'pink':
              this.loopColor = 'pink'
              return true
            break;
          default:

        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>

  *
    box-sizing: border-box
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif

  li
   list-style: none

  .rightTopper
    float: left
    margin-right: 20px
    margin-top: 10px
    font-size: 20px
    font-weight: bold
    .amount
      display: inline-block
      background-color: rgba(0,100,255,0.1)
      padding: 5px
      border-radius: 3px
    img
      display: inline-block
      height: 30px
      width: 30px
    .BCN
      position: absolute
      margin-top: -10px
      font-size: 15px
      color: gray


</style>
```

Comment: what's the point of setting `this.loopColor`?  Why is using `<span :style="{'color': item.painted}">` not enough ?

Comment: Because I want to use hex color values depending on many factors in the future. `item.painted` is only a string representation when printing the color name on the screen so to say. @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with your [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement syntax.

On your `getColor` method:

```
getColor: function(color) {
    switch (color) {
      case color === 'pink':
          this.loopColor = 'pink'
          return true
        break;
      default:

    }
  }
```

Your `case` statement is incorrect.

```
case color === 'pink':
```

It should be just:

```
case 'pink':
```

See this working JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/299194/

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
      {{ item.name }}
      <span :style="{'color': getColor(item.painted)}">
        {{ item.painted }}
      </span>
```

or better yet, to prevent using functions in the template this way, you may be better off either updating the data or using an additional variable.

```
      {{ item.name }}
      <span :style="{'color': getColor(item.myHexColor)}">
        {{ item.painted }}
      </span>
```

where `myHexColor` gets added toe the items before render

Comment: Yeah I guess I could just do it with variables instead, which I am now. Thanks!

Comment: Using variables is a preferred way. Having functions inside your template can slow down rendering, having a function call like this inside the loop can have a severe impact on performance that may only be noticeable once you have many items.